# Lightning on Mars?

Tags: mars, planetary-science, weather

I watched the movie The Martian, and there is a brief scene where there is lightning on Mars. Something about this seems unlikely to me, but I can't remember if it's actually possible or not. Is there actually lightning on Mars?

Answer (score 11):

Lightning has been observed in Mars. However, this is ['dry' lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_lightning), unrelated to precipitation.

This was described in the paper [*Emission of non-thermal microwave radiation by a Martian dust storm*](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2009GL038715/full) by Christopher Ruf and others.